# How is ethereum updated?

Tags: eth-2.0

I've been reading up on crypto recently, and saw that ethereum is going to change to pos in the future.

I imagine that this entails all miners downloading an updated mining client? However, two things:

1. During the transition, will there not be a time when only a fraction of the people have updated, and the people using the old client will not accept the results of the new clients? How does this work? Especially, during the transition, will there not be some minutes/hours/however long it take in which a 51% attack is relatively easy?
2. Is it possible that there is a fraction of people who just decide to keep using the old client and keep building the current pow blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

Danny Ryan made an enlightening [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8N10a1EBhBc) concerning the merge. He explains that if everything goes according to plan, the transition shouldn't be "felt" by anyone other than minors and validators.

The way it works is that current Beacon block will, after the merge, contain all the info of the current mainnet block:

[image]

Once Beacon Block will start to record data previoulsy on the mainnet blocks, even if some minors continue to mine they will not be taken into account because they won't be included in Beacon blocks.

The post-merge client architecture will resemble this:
[image]
(source: https://tim.mirror.xyz/sR23jU02we6zXRgsF_oTUkttL83S3vyn05vJWnnp-Lc)

The Beacon node will run a particular consensus client and the Execution engine will run an execution client (probably Geth according to https://clientdiversity.org/).